# Connections Option in RDS Mysql and best way to handle many connections

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In the below image it shows current activity as 99 Connections.
How exactly it is counted.

RDS is accessed through node.js webservices, php website. Every time I do some operations I close the connection. So once after closing it doesn't decrease rather it keeps increasing. Later I got the too many connections error message once the connections became 608. I restarted then it works.  I never seen it decreasing.

So what is the best way I can handle it.

[image]

Below is the image which is showing when I run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP-based web pages that use a MySQL connection generally exit as soon as they're done rendering page content, so the connection gets closed whether you explicitly call a mysqli or PDO close method or not.

The same is not true of Node services, which run for a long time and can therefore easily leak resources. It's probable that you're opening connections, but not closing them, in your Node service, which would produce the sort of behavior you're seeing here. (This is an easy mistake to make, especially for those of us whose background is largely in more ephemeral PHP scripts.)

One good way to identify the problem is to connect to the MySQL instance via Workbench or the console monitor and issue `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` to get a list of currently active connections, their originating hosts, and the queries (if any) they are executing. This may help you narrow down the source of the leaking connections, so that you can identify the code at fault and repair it.

Comment: I have made sure I close the connection in node.js mysqlConnection.end() and php using mysqli_close($con).  But the no of connections showing for db.m3.large is 1000000 in amazon dashboard.

Comment: Sure, but something's still holding connections open. Take a look at the processlist using the command I mentioned in my answer; that should afford at least some insight into what's at fault.

Comment: Aaron I have put the image in original post which executed with your command. That is the information which is given and now its around 278

Comment: OK, so your next step is to look at whatever's running on the host referenced in the process list, connecting as `root` to the database `deccan`, and hunt down the problem from there. Unfortunately, I can't really do a great deal to help with that process from here, since I'm not part of your organization and don't know anything about the details of the code you're running, but at least you know where to start looking from here. Good luck!

Comment: Aaron can you please explain those columns in the image

Comment: Yes, but the MySQL documentation will do a better job of it.